# Node.js and backbone.js assets versioning

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

**I have the following setup:**

- Backend web application built in Node.js
- Frontend web application build in Backbone.js that does Ajax calls to the backend
- Frontend is using SASS to build CSS that contains images

**Now the issue:**

Is there anything "out there" in the internet that can version my images and css files, that can be used by / from node.js or express, like there is Sprockets for Ruby?

**Details:**

By versioning I refer to "image_name"_"sha1_of_the_file".png or something similar, so that every time I change an existing image I would run the "magic script" that will modify the image, and update the css file with it.

PS: I would like to use something already built and not reinvent the wheel if possible, otherwise I could write my own **thing**

Thanks

Comment: [**Grunt**](http://gruntjs.com/) or [**Gulp**](http://gulpjs.com/) maybe?

Comment: I have previously looked to both. What I also need to mention is that I don't need minify or uglify because for that I use require.js. I also don't need image optimization what I would need is possibility to add versions to images that reside in a CSS and also a version to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called cache-busting :

https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683229/cachebusting-using-grunt-for-multiple-js-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683229/cachebusting-using-grunt-for-multiple-js-fileshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683229/cachebusting-using-grunt-for-multiple-js-files)

https://github.com/PaulTondeur/grunt-cache-busting